Is feature importance given by decision tree universal?
I'm wondering that if I have a set of features on a fitted classification decision tree with relative low feature importance, would it mean that these features would also be negligible when fitted with other types of models, such as a neural network or ensembles like XGBoost/LightGBM?
I have seen decision tree being used as a feature selector for linear models quite often, so I'm wondering if this would be extendable.

Are you talking about a classification/regression tree or a random forest? Feature importance is often used in reference to a random forest?

@num_39 clarified it as a classification tree. I think it's applicable for a single classification decision tree too.


Is feature importance given by decision tree universal?

NO
Using random forests to identify important features for linear models presents problems. Random forests can and do pick up on nonlinearity and feature interactions. Linear models do not catch these without those features being made explicit.
In the example below, we consider the following data and want to predict red vs blue.

The red and blue groups are perfectly separable, and a random forest model picks up on this, earning a ROCAUC of one. Such a random forest model would conclude that both the x1 and x2 features are important.
On the other hand, a logistic regression on just the x1 and x2 variables cannot distinguish between red and blue. Are those two variables important determinants of the color? The plot shows that they most certainly are, but the regression gives no such evidence unless you explicitly engineer the interaction feature that the random forest figures out on its own.
In this case, the features found to be important in the random forest are not seen as important in this logistic regression model, no.
library(ggplot2)
library(pROC)
library(randomForest)
set.seed(2024)
N <- 1000
x1_1_0 <- runif(N, -2, -1)
x1_2_0 <- runif(N, 1, 2)
x2_1_0 <- runif(N, -2, -1)
x2_2_0 <- runif(N, 1, 2)
x1_1_1 <- runif(N, -2, -1)
x1_2_1 <- runif(N, 1, 2)
x2_1_1 <- runif(N, 1, 2)
x2_2_1 <- runif(N, -2, -1)
x1 <- c(x1_1_0, x1_2_0, x1_1_1, x1_2_1)
x2 <- c(x2_1_0, x2_2_0, x2_1_1, x2_2_1)
y <- rep(c(0, 1), c(2*N, 2*N))
d <- data.frame(x1 = x1, x2 = x2, y = as.factor(y))

ggplot(d, aes(x = x1, y = x2, col = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")

R <- randomForest::randomForest(
  y ~ .,
  d,
  ntree = 100
  )
L <- glm(y ~ x1 + x2, family = binomial)
preds_R <- predict(R, type = "prob")[, 1]
preds_L <- predict(L, type = "response")
r_R <- pROC::roc(y, preds_R)
r_L <- pROC::roc(y, preds_L)
par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
plot(r_R, main = paste("AUC =", round(r_R$auc, 3)))
plot(r_L, main = paste("AUC =", round(r_L$auc, 3)))
par(mfrow = c(1, 2))

Some Related Links
SHAP algorithm for feature selecion

i feel you have missed that a linear relationship requires an infinite number of piecewise constant functions...so a linear relationship will be considered to have more 'feature importance' than eg a (piecewise) constant effect

@seanv507 Do you mean a different generalized linear model than the logistic regression I used?

no i was referring to this https://explained.ai/rf-importance/

"We've known for years that this common mechanism for computing feature importance is biased; i.e. it tends to inflate the importance of continuous or high-cardinality categorical variables For example, in 2007 Strobl et al pointed out in Bias in random forest variable importance measures: Illustrations, sources and a solution that “the variable importance measures of Breiman's original Random Forest method ... are not reliable in situations where potential predictor variables vary in their scale of measurement or their number of categories.”

With all the steps that go into ML models, it is always important to go back to the basics and study the data step-by-step. I'll write my opinion on the topic with a practical example:
First we need a toy dataset:
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
data = load_iris()
df = pd.DataFrame(data.data, columns=data.feature_names)
df['species'] = data.target
speciesMap = {0: 'setosa', 1: 'versicolor', 2: 'virginica'}
df['species'] = df['species'].map(speciesMap)

We want to classify some stuff, in this case, we want to classify flowers.
How? with data.
What is data? it's hopefully relevant information that can enable us to distinguish between the different flowers.
This is already quite a challenging task. Looking at boxplots and computing statistics starts to become tedious when the number of features and classes starts to increase. So something that can reduce the number of features into something that is more visual might help us quite a bit. This is where dimensionality reduction comes in.
PCA is one of the most common, if not the most common dimensionality reduction techniques. PCA finds new spaces where the data can be reduced to some small number of important dimensions that are generated by the data itself:
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
x = df.drop(['species'], axis=1)  # remove the species' column from dataframe
scaler = StandardScaler()  # start an instance of StandardScaler
xScaled = scaler.fit_transform(x)  # scale
pca = PCA(n_components=2)  # define pca 
xPCA = pca.fit_transform(xScaled)  # apply PCA
pcaDf = pd.DataFrame(data=xPCA, columns=['Principal Component 1', 'Principal Component 2'])  # store PCA scores
plt.figure(figsize=(7, 5))  # new figure
sns.scatterplot(x='Principal Component 1', y='Principal Component 2', hue=df["species"], data=pcaDf)  # scatter
plt.xlabel('Principal Component 1: ' + str(round(100 * pca.explained_variance_ratio_[0], 2)) + " %")  # label with explained variance
plt.ylabel('Principal Component 2: ' + str(round(100 * pca.explained_variance_ratio_[1], 2)) + " %")  # label with explained variance
plt.grid()  # enable grid
loadings = np.abs(pca.components_.T)  # take absolute value of PCA loadings
loadingsDf = pd.DataFrame(loadings, index=data.feature_names, columns=['PC1', 'PC2'])  # dataframe for loadings
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, sharex=True, figsize=(8, 5))  # subplots for each direction
loadingsDf['PC1'].plot(kind='bar', ax=axs[0], color='skyblue')  # bar plot for PC1
axs[0].set_ylabel('Loadings for PC1: ' + str(round(100 * pca.explained_variance_ratio_[0], 2)) + " %")  # label for PC1 with %
axs[0].set_xlabel('Feature')  # x-axis label
loadingsDf['PC2'].plot(kind='bar', ax=axs[1], color='lightgreen')  # bar plot for PC1
axs[1].set_ylabel('Loadings for PC2: ' + str(round(100 * pca.explained_variance_ratio_[1], 2)) + " %")  # label for PC2 with %
axs[1].set_xlabel('Feature')  # x-axis label
for ax in axs:
    ax.grid()  # enable grid for each subplot
plt.suptitle("Kind of a feature importance, but unsupervised")  # suptitle for the plots
plt.xticks(rotation = 0)

By scattering the scores after this dimensionality reduction, we see that indeed the data can be separated without any training needed. One might say that this was an unsupervised way of clustering the data! We see from here that the data mainly separates on the x-axis, this will be important in the next plot.

To know how these two new dimensions were formed, we can look at the PCA loadings:

We see from this that petal length and width are the most important two features for the newly calculated dimension!
Now that this is done, we can look at another way to get feature importance. A supervised way that does not involve any training of models. Remember what I said about calculating statistics becoming tedious? This is how it stops being tedious:
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest, chi2
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()  # create an instance of MinMaxScaler
xScaled = scaler.fit_transform(df[data.feature_names])  # scale the features using MinMaxScaler
x = pd.DataFrame(xScaled, columns=data.feature_names)  # create a dataframe with scaled data
y = df['species']  # select the target variable
chi2Selector = SelectKBest(chi2, k='all')  # create a chi2 selector with 'k=all' to select all features
xKbest = chi2Selector.fit_transform(x, y)  # apply the chi2 selector to the scaled data
# create a dataframe with features and their corresponding chi2 scores and p-values
chi2Scores = pd.DataFrame({
    'Feature': x.columns,
    'Chi2 Score': chi2Selector.scores_,
    'P-values': chi2Selector.pvalues_
})
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 4))
plt.bar(chi2Scores['Feature'], -np.log(chi2Scores['P-values']), color='dodgerblue')  # create a bar plot for importance
plt.ylabel('Importance = -log(p)')  # label the y-axis
plt.title('Feature Importance using Chi2 Test')  # set title of the plot
plt.grid()


Here we see kind of the same pattern of the loadings. This is good, it means that we are seeing consistency in the importance of the features.
Finally, we go with the training of a CART model:
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x = df.drop(['species'], axis=1)  # drop the 'species' column from the DataFrame
y = df['species']  # select the 'species' column as a response
scaler = StandardScaler()
x = scaler.fit_transform(x)  # scale
xTrain, xTest, yTrain, yTest = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)  # split data
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=42)  # create an instance of a DecisionTreeClassifier
clf.fit(xTrain, yTrain)  # fit the classifier
importances = clf.feature_importances_  # get feature importance
featuresDf = pd.DataFrame(data={'Feature': data.feature_names, 'Importance': importances})  # create DataFrame of feature importances
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 4))  # new figure
plt.bar(featuresDf['Feature'], featuresDf['Importance'], color='dodgerblue')  # bar plot for feature importances
plt.title('Feature Importance from Decision Tree')  # title of the plot
plt.xlabel('Features')  # x-axis label
plt.ylabel('Importance')  # y-axis label
plt.grid()

And now for the feature importance from the CART:

We see here that the importance of the petal length is way above anything else. This is the feature that the model relies on the most to separate between the different classes. But does this mean that we should choose the petal length only and disregard the rest? Of course not, I already saw by using no training that some of the other features are very useful.
So no it should not be universal, the way CART models are built differs from other models. Such a selection might exclude important variables that could benefit your modelling task.
